# Is it possible to change fields values in migration?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a lot of posts with no associated user. There are also staging and production databases with different datasets.
Is there some way to set a default user for posts without an associated user?

Comment: You may use `->default($value)` on `user_id` field in migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, sure you need create migration like this:

```
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */   
    public function up()
    {
        $defaultUser = \App\User::first();
        $posts = \App\Post::all();
        
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            if (is_null($post->user)) {
                $post->user()->associate($defaultUser);
                $post->save(['timestamps' => false]);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //

    }
```